# simply login system in flask with "Method Not Allowed" error

Tags: python, html, postgresql, heroku, flask

I am trying do a simple login system with Flask. I found many tutorials tested it and then tried to do something on my own. I'm running my app on Heroku and using a postgresql database. I have some problem but I don't know exactly why? In database there is one user, when I'm puting the login and password and then submiting I'm getting error like this:

> Method Not Allowed
>
> The method is not allowed for the requested URL.

here's fragment of my index.html with login form:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="" method="post" name="login">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
```

run.py

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, login_required
from flask import Flask,session, request, flash, url_for, redirect, render_template, abort, Blueprint
from flask.ext.login import login_user , logout_user , current_user , login_required
import views

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')

#config for Forms
app.config.update(DEBUG = True, SECRET_KEY = 'csefdfdf')

#import aplication views
app.register_blueprint(views.devops)

#conection to database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

#flask-login
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)

login_manager.login_view = 'index'

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('index.html', title='DevOps Nokia')
    email = request.form['inputEmail']
    password = request.form['inputPassword']
    admin = models.User.query.fillter_by(email=email, password=password).first()
    if admin is None or admin.is_admin == False:
        flash('Error, no user!')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    login_user(admin)
    flash('Logged in successfully')
    return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('test'))

def run():
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?
Waiting for ur answers. :)

Comment: What happens if you replace

`@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`

with just

`@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])`

?

Comment: Then I got a message `Bad Request

The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.`

Comment: Please don't store passwords in plaintext. Adding support for password hashing is trivial: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bcrypt/3.1.3#usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure that both of your route definitions for the function have the allowed methods defined:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

As for the `400 Bad Request` error - I believe you are getting this because you are trying to access `request.form['inputPassword']`, but there is no input field in your form with a `name` attribute of `inputPassword`. You'd need to add the `name` attribute as below:

`<input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>`

Also, this use of `fillter` seems to be a typo:

```
admin = models.User.query.fillter_by(email=email, password=password).first()
```

should be:

```
admin = models.User.query.filter_by(email=email, password=password).first()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting bad request you can try to print your request.form so that you can find out which elements are in that list and you should also use get() method

'request.form.get("inputPassword", None)'

and you should also add name attribute in password element of your HTML form.remeber that in flask if you submit any form it will include those elements only who contains name attribute.so here in your case you did not include name attribute in your input password element so it exclude that element from request.form.